# how can i define redirect url in yii framework for twitter oauth

Tags: php, yii

I had added api key and redirect url in config.php

**config.php**

```
<?php
     define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'my consumer key');
     define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'my secrete key');
     define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://localhost:81/web/twitterAPI/process.php');
?>
```

But the redirect url does not call.

And also i want to add external php library file in my program.

I think the file is import to the main.php.

And how to call the external library file.

Answer (score 0):

you using yii framework so you can define redirect url at config main.php file in protected folder like.
you can define like,

```
'params'=>array('redirecturl'=>'[host][controller_name]/[method_name]',),
```

and use for to get

```
echo Yii::app()->params['redirecturl'];
```

i hope help to this code...

Answer (score -1):

You are using yii framework,

So u use redirect url, something like,
[host][controller_name]/[method_name]

```
<?php
     define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'my consumer key');
     define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'my secrete key');
     define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', '[host][controller_name]/[method_name]');
?>
```